# logical consequence question

Tags: logic

Let F and G be two propositional formulas.
Is it true that F |= G or F |= ¬G?
Answer from teacher:
It is not true that F |= G or F |= ¬G for any F and G.
For instance, neither p |= q nor p |= ¬q hold for
propositional variables p and q.

But I really don't understand, can someone give me an example or explain it more clearly?

Comment: It is exactly as said from you teacher; to say that $F \vDash G$ means that **every** truth assignment that satisfies $F$ will also satsify $G$. But for $p$ and $q$ prop variables we may have a turth assignment $v_1$ such that $v_1(p)= \text T$ and $v_1(q)=\text F$, and thus it is **not** true that $p \vDash q$. And a second truth assignment $v_2$ such that $v_2(p)=v_2(q)=\text T$ and thus also $p \vDash \lnot q$ does not hold.

Comment: *What* do you not understand? How the example is a counter example to the general question, or why the example does not hold?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a concrete example from real life. Consider two statements:

$F$: Bananas are yellow

$G$: There is a dime in my wallet

Now, does $F$ logically imply $G$? Will bananas being yellow force me to have a dime in my wallet?  Clearly not!

OK, does $F$ logically imply $\neg G$? Will bananas being yellow force me *not* to have a dime in my wallet?  No, that also does not follow.

So, at least intuitively, if a statement $F$ has nothing to say about some completely different stateent $G$ then neither $G$ nor its negation $\neg G$ is implied by $F$.

Our mathematical system of logic reflects this:

The fact that you can set $F$ to True and $G$ to False means that $F \not \vDash G$. And, the fact that I can set both $F$ and $G$ to True means that $F \not \vDash \neg G$.